# Changing an ImageView to black and white

Tags: android

I would like to change an ImageView's image to black and white. The only thing is my code allows the user to take a photo, that photo is placed in the imageview. I would like that photo to be black and white. If anyone knows how I could do this, I would appreciate it.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.triptych4;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    // label our logs "CameraApp3"
    private static String logtag = "CameraApp3";
    // tells us which camera to take a picture from
    private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    // empty variable to hold our image Uri once we store it
    private Uri imageUri;

    private Integer[] pics = { R.drawable.android, R.drawable.android3d,
          R.drawable.background3 };

    private ImageView imageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        gallery.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, 
                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pic:" + arg2, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageView.setImageResource(pics[arg2]);
            }
        });


        // look for the button we set in the view
        ImageButton cameraButton = (ImageButton)
                findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
        // set a listener on the button
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);

    }




    // set a new listener
    private OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // open the camera and pass in the current view
            takePhoto(v);
        }
    };

    public void takePhoto(View v) {
        // tell the phone we want to use the camera
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        // create a new temp file called pic.jpg in the "pictures" storage area of the phone
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "pic.jpg");
        // take the return data and store it in the temp file "pic.jpg"
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        // stor the temp photo uri so we can find it later
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        // start the camera
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context context;
        int imageBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView imageView =new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
            return imageView;
        }
    } 
    // override the original activity result function
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // call the parent
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
        // if the requestCode was equal to our camera code (1) then...
        case 1:
            // if the user took a photo and selected the photo to use
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // get the image uri from earlier
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                // notify any apps of any changes we make
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                // get the imageView we set in our view earlier
                ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
                // create a content resolver object which will allow us to access the image file at the uri above
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                // create an empty bitmap object
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                    // get the bitmap from the image uri using the content resolver api to get the image
                    bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                    // set the bitmap to the image view
                    imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    // notify the user
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    // notify the user
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(logtag, e.toString());
                }
            }


        }


    }



}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.triptych5.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_camera"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_camera"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="235dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/middle4" />

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by doing:

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.setSaturation(0);

ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
imageview.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Comment: is teh default satuation 100?

Comment: No, default is 1, it's float

Answer (score 17):

This is the **Kotlin** Version

```
imageView.colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(ColorMatrix().apply { setSaturation(0f)})
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `android.graphics.ColorFilter` for your purpose.

You can use this sample to suite your need.
Pass the `imageView` to the `setBW` method like

```
setBW(imageView);
```

and the the functionality is

```
private void setBW(ImageView iv){

     float brightness = 10; // change values to suite your need

     float[] colorMatrix = { 
             0.33f, 0.33f, 0.33f, 0, brightness,
             0.33f, 0.33f, 0.33f, 0, brightness, 
             0.33f, 0.33f, 0.33f, 0, brightness,
             0, 0, 0, 1, 0    
           };

     ColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
        iv.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }
```

Try using this. Any concerns. Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: For those who want to understand a bit more about how this works, here is a great article about `ColorMatrixColorFilter`: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/android-image-color-change-with-colormatrix-e927d7fb6eb4

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest using Kotlin extensions:

```
private const val MAX_SATURATION = 1f
private const val MIN_SATURATION = 0f

fun ImageView.setMaxSaturation() {
    val matrix = ColorMatrix()
    matrix.setSaturation(MAX_SATURATION)

    colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix)
}

fun ImageView.setMinSaturation() {
    val matrix = ColorMatrix()
    matrix.setSaturation(MIN_SATURATION)

    colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java** version in one line

imageview.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new ColorMatrix(){{setSaturation(0f);}}));

Comment: ...why? Cramming everything onto one line has no benefit whatsoever, and when it hinders clarity it is actively harmful.

Comment: I found it very helpful, to understand the essence of the solution without unnecessary variables. Of course, I will never write code like this for any project. But, I wanted to disagree with you about this solution having "no benefit whatsoever". I loved it!