# How to change android jetpack compose bottomAppBar icon tint color?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomnavigationview

BottomNavigationBar() can only take the `background` and `contentColor` but there is no option for tint color.

Answer (score 55):

If you want to change the tint color of the image then you can use the `colorFilter` property of the `Image`

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_details), 
    contentDescription = "", 
    colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.Black)
)
```

Answer (score 44):

If you want to remove completly the tint color and you would like to use icon's colors then try with: `tint = Color.Unspecified`

For example:

```
Icon(
    modifier = Modifier.size(34.dp),
    imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_your_icon),
    contentDescription = "Some icon",
    tint = Color.Unspecified
)
```

Answer (score 19):

In case you didn't want to change content color, and wanted to have an individual color for specific Icon, there is a tint property. Like:

```
Icon(
 Icons.Filled.PushPin, "",
 tint = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary
)
```

But as others said, you can use `unselectedContentColor` and `selectedContentColor` in your `NavigationItem`.

Answer (score 9):

For `BottomNavigation`, you need to provide `BottomNavigationItem` to construct it, while constructing `BottomNavigationItem`, you can use `Icon` with `tint` as resource like below

```
BottomNavigation() {
    BottomNavigationItem(icon = { 
           Icon(asset = vectorResource(id = R.drawable.homeBottomNav), tint = Color.Blue) //this is tint
       }, selected = true, onClick = {})
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the `1.0.0` (tested with `1.0.0-beta06`) in the **`BottomNavigationItem`** you can define the attributes:

- **`selectedContentColor`**
- **`unselectedContentColor`**

Something like:

```
    BottomNavigation(backgroundColor = Color.White) {
            BottomNavigationItem(
                selectedContentColor = Color.Red,
                unselectedContentColor = Color.Gray,
                icon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "contentDescription")
                },
                selected = true,
                onClick = {})
            BottomNavigationItem(
                selectedContentColor = Color.Red,
                unselectedContentColor = Color.Gray,
                icon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Search, "contentDescription")
                },
                selected = false,
                onClick = {})
    }
```

[image]

Also since the default `selectedContentColor` is based on the `LocalContentColor.current` you can also use something like:

```
    BottomNavigation(backgroundColor = Color.White) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides Color.Red) {
            BottomNavigationItem(
                icon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "contentDescription")
                },
                selected = true,
                onClick = {})
            BottomNavigationItem(
                icon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Search, "contentDescription")
                },
                selected = false,
                onClick = {})
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: you should change `selected` dynamically!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unselectedContentColor` and `selectedContentColor`.

```
BottomNavigationItem(
   unselectedContentColor = Color.Black,
   selectedContentColor = Color.Red,
   icon = {
       Icon(
           painter = painterResource(id = screen.iconResourceId),
           contentDescription = null)
           },
    selected = currentRoute == screen.route,
    onClick = { }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`selectedContentColor` changes color of `Text` and `Icon`, **but** not `Image()` Composable. So if you want to keep color of multicolor-icon when selected, one should use `Image()`. Also you want to make it grayscale when unselected, [you can use colorFilter.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67013513/3736955)

Plus if you don't want to change color of `Text/Icon`, then you can use `Color.Unspecified`.

Answer (score 0):

This is for rating menu, product or something like that. I hope you benefit from it.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                repeat(5) { index ->
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Star,
                        contentDescription = "Star$index",
                        tint = if (index < rating) Color.Yellow else Color.Gray,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(13.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
```